# I got an error while using "git push heroku master" command

Tags: python, git, heroku

When I'm trying to push python project on heroku using `git push heroku master`
command I got an error like this.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your ssh keys to heroku by running `heroku keys:add`. Heroku can then verify you and allow access to your repository on heroku. More on this here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys